# django nested body request not being set

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a request to the box api using python and django. I'm getting a `400  Entity body should be a correctly nested resource attribute name\\/value pair` error.

My requests looks like:

```
requests.options(headers.kwargs['url'], headers=headers.headers, 
                 data={'parent': {'id': 'xxxx'}, 'name': 'name.pdf'})
```

When I inspect the `400` request.body it contains `'parent=id&name=name.pdf'` which leads me to believe I'm not setting the body properly

A curl works with the body

`-d '{"name": "name.pdf", "parent": {"id": "xxxxx"}}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly encode the dictionary to prevent form-encoding. Otherwise, it will be form-encoded as the way similar to [`urllib.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) (or [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) in Python 3.x).

```
import json

...

requests.options(
    headers.kwargs['url'], headers=headers.headers, 
    data=json.dumps({'parent': {'id': 'xxxx'}, 'name': 'name.pdf'}))
```

In other word, instead of passing a dictionary, pass a string.

---

According to [More complicated POST requests - Request documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

> ...
>   There are many times that you want to send data that is not
>   form-encoded. If you pass in a string instead of a dict, that data
>   will be posted directly.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. I'm now getting a `401` response though. When I remove the json.dumps it goes back to a `400`. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2954587, No clue. Could you post a new question with full traceback?